# Python login counter

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and am trying to create a simple login with a faux OTP system and login limiter. The OTP works, but the counter for the login limiter doesn't. It gives me the desired result after only one failed attempt (I want 3). The output after a failed attempt is:

ACCESS LOCKED. YOU DON'T DESERVE TO SEE WHAT'S HERE. GOODBYE.

Incorrect Username or Password. Please try again.

Incorrect Username or Password. Please try again.

Incorrect Username or Password. Please try again.

Process finished with exit code 1

Here's the code:

```
def old_acc():
count = 0  # count created to limit number of failed logins
login = input("Username:    ")  # prompts user to login in with their username
pw = input("Password:   ")  # prompts user to login in with their password
while count <= 3:
    for line in open("db.txt", "r").readlines():
        acc_info = line.split()

        # if username and pw do not match, prompt user to try again
        if login != acc_info[0] and pw != acc_info[1]:
            print("\nIncorrect Username or Password. Please try again.\n")
            count += 1
        # if username and pw match, login is successful; generate otp
        else:
            gen_otp()
            print("ACCESS GRANTED")
            access_info()

        # if failure count is = 3, deny access and lock out.
        if count == 3:
            # stops code and doesn't allow any further input.
            sys.exit("ACCESS LOCKED. YOU DON'T DESERVE TO SEE WHAT'S HERE. GOODBYE.")
```

Here's the code for the OTP generation, for reference.

```
def gen_otp():
    digits = "0123456789"  # digits for OTP generation
    otp = ""

    for i in range(4):
        otp += digits[math.floor(random.random() * 10)]
    mbox("Enter OTP", otp, 1)  # gives user message with OTP
    otp_input = input("Enter OTP:   ")

    if otp == otp_input:
        print("ACCESS GRANTED")
        access_info()

    return otp
```

Thanks.

Comment: fixed the indentation of `gen_otp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop checks every line in the `db.txt` file and increments the counter if it doesn't match the password. Given that the `db.txt` probably contains more than 1 password, the counter will already reach 4 in the first attempt. You want to increment the counter only if NO line of db.txt matches the password.

```
def old_acc():
   count = 0  # count created to limit number of failed logins
   success = False # keeps track of succesful login
   while count <= 3 and not success:
      login = input("Username:    ")  # prompts user to login in with their username
      pw = input("Password:   ")  # prompts user to login in with their password

       for line in open("db.txt", "r").readlines():
          acc_info = line.split()

           # if username and pw match, login is successful; generate otp
           if login == acc_info[0] and pw == acc_info[1]:
               gen_otp()
               print("ACCESS GRANTED")
               access_info()
               success = True
               break

        # if username and pw do not match, prompt user to try again
    if not success:
        print("\nIncorrect Username or Password. Please try again.\n")
        count += 1

    # if failure count is = 3, deny access and lock out.
    if count == 3:
        # stops code and doesn't allow any further input
        sys.exit("ACCESS LOCKED. YOU DON'T DESERVE TO SEE WHAT'S HERE. GOODBYE.")
```